How to find a gradient based on more than the previous value?
I have an array with a peak value of 180. I am trying to find the gradient of the array at the peak. I am using the following to get the gradient:
def first_derivative(array, dx=1, axis=-1):
    return np.gradient(array, dx, axis=axis)

But the problem with this is it sees only the previous value to compute the gradient, but the value in the array slowly increases to 180 by two or three and this three is getting captured in the gradient. I tried using a gaussian filter on the array to get the gradient to be 30, but I wasn't able to achieve. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
I compute the gaussian by:
a = cv2.getGaussianKernel(3, 29) 
# scaled_w = (w - np.min(w)) / (np.max(w) - np.min(w))
array_1d = w.reshape(-1, 1)
print(array_1d.shape, a.shape)
result_array = sig.convolve2d(array_1d, a, mode="same")


